# Show that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f = 2\int_0^\pi f $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

If $f:[-\pi, \pi]→\mathbb{R}$ is an even function i.e. $f(x)=f(-x)$ show that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f = 2\int_0^\pi f $.

I think I'm close but just can't quite do the last step. This is what I have so far:

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f = \int_{-\pi}^{0} f + \int_{0}^{\pi} f = \int_{0}^{-\pi} -f + \int_{0}^{\pi} f = -1 \int_{0}^{-\pi} f + \int_{0}^{\pi} f $

Am I allowed to multiply the limits of the first inegral by the $-1$ outside the integral? If so then how do I prove this is allowed?

Comment: HINT: What are the properties of an even function? And yeah you are almost there :P

Answer (score 3):

By change of variable,

$\int_{-\pi}^{0} f(x)dx=\int_{\pi}^{0} f(-x)-dx=\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)dx$

For the last equality, we use $f$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is an even function, the graph of $f$ for positive $x$ is a mirror image of the graph for negative $x$. Hence, for $0\leq a\leq b\leq\pi$,

$$\int_{-b}^{-a} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^b f(x) dx$$

and setting $a=0, b=\pi$ gives

$$\int_{-\pi }^{0} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^\pi f(x) dx$$

and

$$\int_{-\pi }^{\pi} f(x) dx=\underbrace{\int_{-\pi}^0 f(x) dx}_{\int_0^\pi f(x)dx}+\int_{0}^\pi f(x) dx=2\int_0^\pi f(x)dx$$